# Reusable Dropdown with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As I got from React documentation using hooks do not require big code refactoring and can be easily included in the existing code. I want to make reusable dropdowns, being called from react component render method.
Here is my code:

```
//navigation.js
import {DropdownToggler} from './dropdown.js';
export class ErrorTriangle extends Component {
   render(){
     return(
        {DropdownToggler({uiElement: {
            toggler: <img src={MyImg}/>,
            field: <div className={'errorMessage'}>
                       <p>Dropdown content</p>
                   </div >
        }})
       }
     )
   }
}

//dropdown.js
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import {store} from "../api/redux/store";

const DropdownToggler = (props) => {
    const myRef = useRef(null);
    const [showField, setShow] = useState(false);
    const isMobile = store.getState().isMobile;

   const remove = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (myRef && myRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
        return
    }
    setShow(false);
    if (isMobile===true) {
        document.removeEventListener('touchend', remove, false)
    } else {
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', remove, false)
    }
};

const show = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (showField) {
        return
    }
    setShow(true);
    if (isMobile===true) {
        document.addEventListener('touchend', remove, false)
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', remove, false)
    }
};

return (
    <>
        {React.cloneElement(props.uiElement.toggler, {
            onTouchEnd: (e) => show(e),
            onMouseUp: isMobile ? null : (e) => show(e)
        })}

        {showField ? React.cloneElement(props.uiElement.field, {ref: node => myRef.current= node}) : null}
    </>
)
};
export {DropdownToggler};
```

And get the error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.
I have already checked existing information about this issue:

1. react-hot-loader version is 4.8.0
2. My react and react-dom are same version 16.8.4;
3. My babel-config contains:

   ```
   'use strict';

   module.exports = {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
      plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "jsx-control-statements", "react-hot-loader/babel"],
   };
   ```

Maybe the problem is that I am breaking the rules of hooks https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html. Will appreciate detailed explanations (examples) or ideas why this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
export class ErrorTriangle extends Component {
   render(){
     return(
        {DropdownToggler({uiElement: {
            toggler: <img src={MyImg}/>,
            field: <div className={'errorMessage'}>
                       <p>Dropdown content</p>
                   </div >
        }})
       }
     )
   }
}
```

To

```
export function ErrorTriangle (props) {
     return(
        {DropdownToggler({uiElement: {
            toggler: <img src={MyImg}/>,
            field: <div className={'errorMessage'}>
                       <p>Dropdown content</p>
                   </div >
        }})
       }
     )
}
```

**OR**

Change

```
{DropdownToggler({uiElement: {
            toggler: <img src={MyImg}/>,
            field: <div className={'errorMessage'}>
                       <p>Dropdown content</p>
                   </div >
        }})
       }
```

To

```
{<DropdownToggler uiElement={{
    toggler: <img src={MyImg}/>,
    field: <div className={'errorMessage'}>
                <p>Dropdown content</p>
            </div >
  }}/>
}
```

**Explanation**

To put it simply if you are using class you should call your component function like this `<Component />` and not like a normal function `Component()` or you can change from using class to using component function

Comment: @ip both of the above solutions should work. If none works tell me so

Comment: I knew about the first suggestion, but that did not fit my needs. The second option - works fine! Thanks!