# Importing external React components to nextJS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a functional component in my own library that I'm importing into a nextJS project, and for some reason it's not recognized as a react functional component.

Example of my library code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
export function Dialog(){
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (<>
             // some jsx logic
            </>)

}
```

importing it in my nextJS component:

```
import { Dialog } from '@myNamespace/library';
```

When I try to use

```
<Dialog />
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

So I logged out a local react component with the Dialog and found that while the local react component seems to be on the namespace `react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default`, my imported component just remains a plain function instead of a react component.

Any ideas as to why NextJS isn't importing my function as a react component?

**EDIT:**

Here's something really interesting: When I remove the hook, nextJS seems to think it is a react component. But when I put the hook in, it doesn't - and throws that error.

**SOLUTION**
For anyone who's interested - the issue was that my package was `npm link` into my project. So in that case there's issues with it not packaging up the components correctly.

Comment: You need to import a default without the braces: `import Dialog from '@myNamespace/library';`

Comment: Have you tried using an arrow function instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reusable Dropdown with React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55053269/reusable-dropdown-with-react-hooks)

Comment: @evgenifotia it's not the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your react and react-dom isn't updated to the standard for hooks try `yarn add react@18.6 react-dom@18.6`

Comment: I'll check! Thanks!

Comment: I just checked both projects - they're all on `16.8.6`

Comment: we need to see what the Dialog code looks like to be able to solve.

Comment: I can't really share the full logic, but I added the part that has the hook in it. It seems nextJS thinks I'm just putting a hook in a regular component. So it doesn't think my Dialog() function is a react functional component.

Comment: Here's something really interesting: When I remove the hook, nextJS seems to think it is a react component. But when I put the hook in, it doesn't - and throws that error.

Comment: its really hard for me to say with not being able to see that whole component, possible you have a github link or something?

Comment: Sorry I know it's frustrating, but for what it's worth - the problem reproduces just the same with exactly the code above (replace the comment with a text node "Hello").

Adding hook reproduces the issue, removing it means nextJS uses the function as react.